# A short-circuiting Promise.allSerial(), without async-await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I need to execute a series of async tasks such that a task is executed *if and only if* the task immediately previous to it in the series gets successfully executed. I also need to collect the partial or full set of results of these tasks. So, if the 3rd task failed, I need the results of the first two tasks.

Now, I can very easily and elegantly use the *async-await* style of promises to implement the above and can even get it working to my satisfaction, however *not* the following non-*async-await* version:

```
  // an async task that fails on an input of 200
  function task(timeout) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log(`Starting a ${timeout}ms task... `);
      if (timeout == 200) {
        console.log(`Starting a ${timeout}ms task... FAILED. timeout = ${timeout}`);
        reject(`task(${timeout}): FAILED`);
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
          let result = timeout * 10;
          output.push(result);
          console.log(`Starting a ${timeout}ms task... done. Result: ${result}`);
          resolve();
        }, timeout);
      }
    });
  }

  let input = [400, 300, 200, 100, 50];
  let output = [];

  let p = Promise.resolve(); // initialize
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
    let timeout = input[i];
    p = p
      .then(() => {
        return task(timeout);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        throw e;
      });
  }

  p = p.finally(() => {
    console.log(`Results so far: ${output.join(", ")}`);
  });
```

**Output**

```
Starting a 400ms task... 
Starting a 400ms task... done. Result: 4000
Starting a 300ms task... 
Starting a 300ms task... done. Result: 3000
Starting a 200ms task... 
Starting a 200ms task... FAILED. timeout = 200
Results so far: 4000, 3000
(node:1882) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: task(200): FAILED
(node:1882) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:1882) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**Question:**

I am very much handling the rejected promise in a `.catch()`, yet I'm getting the above warning. Why?

**Platform:**

Node: 12.8.3

OS: Mac OSX 10.14.4

Comment: why don't you want to use the async await if it works?

Comment: @Liam To learn the `.then()` / `.catch()` style of programming should I run into legacy code.

Comment: that is very odd @Harry ... you know async/await before .then/.catch/.finally!! noting wrong with it ... but ... I'm surprised!

Comment: @JaromandaX no suprises there. The `async-await` version, even though gets compiled/transpiled into a `.then`/`.catch` based version, is more 'linear' to grok for humans (like me, coming from a non-Promises background). For example, when a `reject` happens in an `async-await` based implementation, an exception gets thrown which I can `try-catch` to break out of the `for`-loop. This can also be useful as then I don't even have to chain rest of my tasks once a task has already failed. (Imagine a 10K-task series for the sake of argument!)

Comment: @Harry - yeah, I see your point ... but are you really a javascript programmer if you haven't experienced callback hell :p and that's pre-promises :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Didn't quite get your point. I /have/ seen CB hell (aka Pyramid of Doom). That in fact brought me to Promises in the first place. However, since `async-await` got added only later, I presume I'd run into raw, `.then/.catch` -based legacy code now and then, so want to make sure I have a good, solid understanding of it. IMO, no one, online source (not even MDN docs) does an thorough job explaining Promises. I eg want internals that are more readable than the ECMAScript spec, yet more detailed than the MDN docs.... in pseudocode form... covering `.then/.catch/.finally`.

Comment: @JaromandaX Btw, just 'discovered' that `Promise.resolve(123).finally(() => { console.log("resolve - finally"); });` works as expected, but `Promise.reject(345).finally(() => { console.log("reject - finally"); });` warns about the missing `.catch`! Stuff like this isn't documented in MDN docs for `.finally` and confuses newbies that are told `.then/.catch/.finally` are like `try/catch/finally`. But can't complain too much, am grateful for whatever is available :-)

Comment: but if you try/finally (without the catch) you also don't catch any error and an error is thrown, isn't it? so it's the same -if you want to catch an error, you use catch/.catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.catch((e) => {
  throw e;
});
```

That's not handling the error ... that's throwing one!!

Handle the error on `p` because you don't really want to handle the error in `task` since that would mean the tasks following the rejected one would actually run. Obviously, you don't want that!

```js
// an async task that fails on an input of 200
function task(timeout) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`Starting a ${timeout}ms task... `);
    if (timeout == 200) {
      console.log(`Starting a ${timeout}ms task... FAILED. timeout = ${timeout}`);
      reject(`task(${timeout}): FAILED`);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        let result = timeout * 10;
        output.push(result);
        console.log(`Starting a ${timeout}ms task... done. Result: ${result}`);
        resolve();
      }, timeout);
    }
  });
}

let input = [400, 300, 200, 100, 50];
let output = [];

let p = Promise.resolve(); // initialize
for (let i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
  let timeout = input[i];
  p = p
    .then(() => {
      return task(timeout);
    });
}

p = p
  .catch(() => {}) // error handled!
  .finally(() => {
    console.log(`Results so far: ${output.join(", ")}`);
  });
```

As an alternative ...

- removing the `output.push` from `task` and moving it to where the tasks are executed
- simplifying the loop

You can do

```js
function task(timeout) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`Starting a ${timeout}ms task... `);
    if (timeout == 200) {
      console.log(`Starting a ${timeout}ms task... FAILED. timeout = ${timeout}`);
      reject(`task(${timeout}): FAILED`);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        let result = timeout * 10;
        console.log(`Starting a ${timeout}ms task... done. Result: ${result}`);
        resolve(result); // resolve the result
      }, timeout);
    }
  });
}
let input = [400, 300, 200, 100, 50];
let output = [];
               // adding the result to output here vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
let p = input.reduce((p, t)=>p.then(() => task(t)).then(r => output.push(r)), Promise.resolve());
p
.catch((e) => {})
.finally(() => console.log(`Results so far: ${output.join(", ")}`))
```